# ArcGIS Field Calculator reformat Lat Long values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have a table which is filled with point values that have been exported from an external source. Unfortunately the Lat Long values are formatted strangely and this is preventing me from simply displaying XY data to add the points to the map.

An example Latitude value is: 15 13 51S

I am wanting to create a field calculation in a new field which can convert that value into a decimal degree value so I can easily display the XY data.

My understanding is that I need to split the value into four parts (the degrees, minutes, seconds and direction values) and then divide the minutes value by 60, divide the seconds value by 3600, add those two values to the degree value and assign a negative value if the direction is S.

I have little experience using field calculator for complex calculations like this.

How can Python can be used to do it?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/converting-degrees-minutes-seconds-values-to-decim.htm

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work when the data is set up with a direction (E, W, N, S) instead of just positivie or negative values.

Comment: The only bit not in the duplicate is dealing with the cardinal directions but that is the easiest bit because the last character in your string being W or S just means you need to multiply DD by -1.

Comment: When it says N, W, E or S it isn't specifying a direction per. se. the conventions are N is above the equator, S is below, W and E are with regards to the Prime Meridian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian . Values ending (Value[-1:] for the last character) with S or W are negative in a Cartesian sense. Use int(Value[:-1].split(' ')[0]) + float((Value[:-1].split(' ')[1]))/60 + float((Value[:-1].split(' ')[1]))/3600 then multiply by -1 if the trailing character is W or S. Note that this will have problems if there isn't exactly 3 elements.